# Why do some static site generators use README.md instead of index.md?

Tags: markdown

Why would a static site generator use anything but index.md as the root page for a site? It seems perfectly natural, yet for example VuePress and GitHub expect a README.md instead. I am trying to understand the reasoning for this as I work on Yet Another SSG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why do some static site generators use README.md instead of index.md?

Because repository hosts give README files special treatment. For example, GitHub, Bitbucket, GitLab, etc all display the README file of a directory when a user is browsing through the source files. In some instances, the host site will even protest if a README is not present.

Naturally, the content of a README would often be the same content which one would find in an index file. And, of course, users do not want to maintain two separate files with the same content. And if they do, the Static Site Generator needs to exclude the README file when building the site. Therefore, users ask for, and static site generators add the option to use a README file as the index file for a directory. It makes for cleaner source files and keeps things DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

Personally, I never needed the feature myself (I'm indifferent to the missing README when browsing the source files on GitHib, etc.). However, as one of the developers of MkDocs (a static site generator), this was one of the most requested features until we added it. Now that it exists, we hear nothing about it. The one tweak we needed to make was to ensure the README file is ignored if an index file also exists in the same directory (apparently, there are some users who maintain both files with different content in each -- in those cases, the content of the README is generally not to be included in the built site; however, this seems to be the rarest use case). It would seem that those who want the feature make use of it without issue and those who do not need it are not tripped up by its existence so long as the feature is implemented correctly.